# Is there a way to reduce the resolution of a Stars object in r, similar to the aggregate function in Raster or Terra?

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, terra, r-stars

I am trying to learn the stars package in R, however I am working with data that is very high resolution. I know that that within the Raster package, doing the following:

```
aggregate(raster, factor = 4)
```

Would transform the raster from one that had a 30x30m resolution to one which was 120x120m, for example. Is there a similar way to perform this in stars? When I attempt the aggregate function on a stars object, I get the following error:

> Error in inherits(by, "stars") : argument "by" is missing, with no default

However, I'm not certain what to aggregate by in this case, as I'm really just trying to reduce the overall resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I think `st_warp()` is able to do this. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2020-September/028404.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33648874)

Answer (score 0):

You can use terra methods like this

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(raster)

a <- aggregate(r, factor = 4)

s <- st_as_stars(a)
```